# Migrate to the Twilio Voice 5.0 (iOS 13, Xcode 11): Custom incoming call view controller, reject incoming call issue

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, ios13, twilio-api

I'm migrating iOS app to the Twilio Voice 5.x API (iOS 13 & Xcode 11) and have some questions:

1. My app uses incoming calls. Twilio requires: 3. Report the call to CallKit. Refer to this example for how to report the call to CallKit. 
   My question: Does it mean I can't use more custom incoming call view controller in foreground mode?
2. Right after getting call invite I send request to get info about caller and show it. I do it in background. It worked in previous versions but
   doesn't work now because interruption and handler must work at the same thread and immediately. What do you advise?

Answer (score 0):

2. You can update value on the CallKit inbound call screen by using reportCall like this:

   extension TwilioInteractor: TVONotificationDelegate {

   ```
   func callInviteReceived(_ callInvite: TVOCallInvite) {
       let from = callInvite.from ?? "?"
       let uuid = callInvite.uuid
       displayIncomingCall(from: from, uuid: uuid)
       fetcher.fetchCaller(for: from, callInvite: callInvite) { caller in
           self.updateIncomingCall(from: caller, uuid: uuid)
       }
   }

   private func displayIncomingCall(from: String, uuid: UUID) {
       let callHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: from)
       let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
       callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle
       callUpdate.hasVideo = false
       callUpdate.supportsDTMF = true
       callUpdate.supportsHolding = false
       callUpdate.supportsGrouping = false
       callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = false

       self.callKitProvider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: callUpdate) { (error) in
           if let error = error {
               Log.e("Failed to report incoming call successfully: \(error.localizedDescription).")
           } else {
               Log.twilio("Incoming call successfully reported.")
           }
       }
   }

   private func updateIncomingCall(from: String, uuid: UUID) {
       let callHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: from)
       let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
       callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle
       self.callKitProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: callUpdate)
   }
   ```

   }